Sexual dimorphism on physical attractiveness in the eyes of transgenders
As a general rule, men find features on the most extreme ends of sexual dimorphism physically attractive, but women do not (they prefer something in between), no matter whether they are homosexual/ heterosexual.
One example in Japanese subculture is yaoi (gay manga targeted readers: heterosexual women) VS bara (gay manga targeted readers: gay men). Men in bara are much more masculine than in yaoi.
Effects of sexual dimorphism on facial attractiveness
The masculinity paradox
Sex Differences in Physical Attractiveness
Transgenderism is very under-researched. Do transgenders resemble biological/post-op gender more in regard to this question?
